# Save pandas DataFrame in a way that preserves the type of the timestamp index (existing SO answer does not work?)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

(I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298144/datetime-format-change-when-save-to-csv-file-python) answer but it does not seem to work anymore)

Consider for example `example_1.csv`:

```
timestamp,temp
21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.539000,22
21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.633000,22
21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.633000,22
21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.055000,42
21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.164000,22
21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.164000,22
21-Jun-2017 00:37:12.680000,42
21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.664000,42
21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.664000,42
21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.758000,42
21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.758000,42
```

Ok. In python 3.5:

```
import pandas

>>> pandas.__version__
'0.21.0'


example_df  = pandas.read_csv('example_1.csv', index_col = 0)
example_df.index = pandas.to_datetime(example_df.index, format = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

so far, so good:

```
>>> example_df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-21 00:36:49.539000', '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000',
               '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.055000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:12.680000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
```

But then, I have to save things:

```
example_df.to_csv('example_2.csv', date_format = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
example_df_2  = pandas.read_csv('example_2.csv', index_col = 0)
```

but then, when I read in `example_df_2`'s index, it's not seen as a 
`datetime64[ns]`:

```
>>> example_df_2.index
Index(['21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.539000', '21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.633000',
       '21-Jun-2017 00:36:49.633000', '21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.055000',
       '21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.164000', '21-Jun-2017 00:37:03.164000',
       '21-Jun-2017 00:37:12.680000', '21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.664000',
       '21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.664000', '21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.758000',
       '21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.758000'],
      dtype='object', name='timestamp')
```

This also doesn't help:

```
>>> example_df_2.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 1059, in astype
    return Index(self.values.astype(dtype, copy=copy), name=self.name,
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "21-Jun-2017 00:37:22.758000" at position 3
```

Now this file is yuge and I have to save it in a format I can quickly read it in  latter. I'd rather not have to parse the date timestamp twice if I can avoid it.

So how to fix this? (or what imma doing wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parse_dates` parameter:

```
example_df_2  = pd.read_csv('example_2.csv', index_col = 0, parse_dates=True)
example_df_2.index
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-21 00:36:49.539000', '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000',
               '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.055000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:12.680000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
```

Note, you can do this for the first import also:

```
example_df = pd.read_csv('example_1.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
example_df.index
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-21 00:36:49.539000', '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000',
               '2017-06-21 00:36:49.633000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.055000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000', '2017-06-21 00:37:03.164000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:12.680000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.664000', '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000',
               '2017-06-21 00:37:22.758000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not really what I want: it still is extremely slow, that 'parse_date'. Is there a way to save a pandas df in a way that the datetime index can be read directly (and do not need to be re-parsed)?

Comment: @user189035 No, you can't save datetime directly, because CSV are text files and all text must be parsed somehow.  However, I think the fast way is to read the file in and don't parse dates, then use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')` afterwards.

Comment: Look at the answer I linked to. It seems pandas 0.15 could do it somehow.

Comment: @user189035 That is just storing the date as a text in that particular format. On the way into Python or Excel it still needs to be parsed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, it seems I had misunderstood what the question I linked to was trying to achieve on my initial read. Then, I suppose the best way to not have to re-parse the index at every read is to save the data as a pickle, right?

Comment: @user189035 I have not worked with pickle files enough, I'll do some research in the coming days and let you know what I think.

Comment: I can confirm that If saved in pickle format, you do not need to re-parse the datetimes. On the other hand, I can only use pandas 0.192 and in that version pickled files are not compressed. Still, time is more important than disk space in this application so I can live with uncompressed files, so long as I do not have to reparse the time index everytime.