# Read from file method changes date and time format losing seconds and AM/PM precision

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading some data from a `.tsv` file with python using standard method but even though it reads strings somehow my date and time format changes from `"4/4/2019 6:28:19 PM"` to `"4/4/2019 18:28"`. I am losing seconds and the AM/PM tags.

Using Python3 standard libraries. My data is tab separated like follows;

```
Col1\tTimeStamp\tCol2
val1\t4/4/2019 6:28:19 PM\tval2
```

Here is my `importData` function

```
def importData(file):
    f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    headers, data = f.readline().rstrip('\n').split('\t'), []
    for line in f:
        data += [line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')]
    f.close()
    return headers, data
```

**Update:** When I opened the data with Excel and then applied formatting to the timestamp column, it read just fine. I will look into this further later but so far if anyone else have the same issue this could be a work around or the cause of the issue.

Comment: after line `f = open(..)`, can you show us what is the output of `print(repr(f.read()))`?

Comment: It looks normal. What's causing that?

Comment: Had to edit my first comment I was dealing with the wrong data.

Comment: Update. I was using small portion of the data as a test and when I did repr() thing it looked normal and afterwards even though removed that line it was working fine. Now I am back with the original data and it's too big to fit into memory and repr() is not working. So I am still getting timestamps without the seconds and AM/PM.

Comment: Possibly helpful or related explanation [datetime format change when save to csv file python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30298954/1248974)